# Get touch points in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm newer in sencha. I'm creating a project with a image in panel view. I want touch points in my app for displaying the co-ordinates. How can i get the touch points. Any one can help me.
code:
Ext.define('ImageTouch.view.MyImg1', {
    extend: 'Ext.Img',
    height: 201,
    width: 201,
    src: 'resources/Dan.png',

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
  listeners:[
             {
                element: 'innerElement',
                event: 'tap',
                 fn: function(e) {
                    console.log('TAP!');
                     var x = e.pageX,
                         y = e.pageY;

                     console.log(x ,y);
                }
            }
        ],

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: can you please add some code?

Answer (score 0):

please go through [this](http://icodesnippet.com/search/sencha%20touch%20listener/)
This page explain many examples in senja.
Search under the title "ringingEars/drag n drop javascript to iphone support ( iPhone)".

Please check  [this](https://github.com/nelstrom/Sencha-Touch-listeners-demo) also.